# how to properly use comparison operators within an if-then statement

Tags: shell, unix

What is the best way to perform a check/test for output that comes from a query called within a shell script?

For example,
I have a variable that performs this query:

```
export CHK=`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U foo foobar --tuples-only -c "SELECT 1 AS result FROM pg_database WHERE datname='foo_bar_1234'";`
```

It will return either a `1`=exist or empty string=not exist.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work as expected as it keeps going to
`DB does not exist` everytime even if the value empty string. I even tried it with `"1"` with still the same results.

```
if  [ "$CHCK" = 1 ]; then
        echo "DB exists."
        exit  1
     else
        echo "DB does not exist."
fi
```

How do I correct this and/or what is a better way to check for this?

Comment: "as it keeps going to `DB does not exist` every time even if the value empty string" - that's exactly what your `if` statement is currently designed to do. Are you saying it goes to `DB does not exist` even when `$CHCK` is `1`?   Check the exact value of `$CHCK` - if, for instance, it contains whitespace around `1`, the test will fail. The `if` statement itself is intrinsically OK.

Comment: Well if the `$CHK` comes up with empty string, then echo `DB does not exit` and program continues to next step is what I'm after. As for the whitespace around `1` that is entirely possible. How can I clean that up?

Comment: Can you use `bash`, or does your code need to be strictly POSIX-compliant?

Comment: yes, i believe i can use bash as i've been doing `"#!/bin/bash"` and yes, from running that command manually, it does yield some white space around the `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments it sounds that an output of `1` may be surrounded by whitespace, so one solution is to trim leading and trailing whitespace first, using `read`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export CHCK=$(psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U foo foobar --tuples-only -c "SELECT 1 AS result FROM pg_database WHERE datname='foo_bar_1234'")

# Remove leading and trailing whitespace from the value.
read -r CHCK <<<"$CHCK"

# With whitespace trimmed, comparison with string '1' should now work as intended.
if  [[ $CHCK == '1' ]]; then
  echo "DB exists."
  exit  1
else
  echo "DB does not exist."
fi
```

- Note that unless you truly need to add `$CHCK` to the *environment* so that *child* processes can see it, there's no need to use `export`.
- `read -r CHCK <<<"$CHCK"` takes advantage of the fact that `read` by default removes leading and trailing whitespace from the input when reading into a single variable:

  - `-r` ensures that `\` instances in the input are left untouched - not strictly necessary here, but good practice in general.
  - `<<<` is a so-called `bash` [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString), which simply sends its argument via *stdin* to the command at hand - which is where `read` reads from. `<<<` is a single-line alternative to the POSIX-compliant [here-documents](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument).

---

Another option is to use `bash`'s regex-matching operator, `=~`, which bypasses the need to trim whitespace first:

```
if [[ $CHCK =~ ^[[:space:]]*1[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then # ...
```

---

Less stringently, if the presence of `1` *anywhere* in the string is sufficient, using `bash`'s pattern matching:

```
if [[ $CHCK == *1* ]]; then # ...
```

---

Even less stringently, if the string is truly *empty* (as opposed to *blank*, meaning composed only of whitespace characters) in the non-existence case:

```
if [[ -n $CHCK ]]; then # ... matches *any nonempty* string
```

---

Since the question is generically tagged `shell`, here's the **POSIX-compliant equivalent** of the first solution:

```
export CHCK=$(psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U foo foobar --tuples-only -c "SELECT 1 AS result FROM pg_database WHERE datname='foo_bar_1234'")

# Remove leading and trailing whitespace from the value.
read -r CHCK <<EOF
$CHCK
EOF

# With whitespace trimmed, comparison with string '1' should now work as intended.
if [ "$CHCK" = '1' ]; then
  echo "DB exists."
  exit  1
else
  echo "DB does not exist."
fi
```

- Note the use of a here-document (`<<`) instead of the bash-specific here-string (`<<<`), and the `[ ... ]` (single-bracket) conditional form with the *double-quoted* variable reference.

Comment: This works great! Thank you. Can you elaborate on the `read`. Why `<<<`? wonder how that works.

Comment: @noober: My pleasure; I'm glad to hear it. Re `<<<`: see my update.

Comment: Great answer and explanation. Thanks again!